# Oracle error using oracledb: ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: python, oracle, python-oracledb, oracle-wallet

im trying to use oracledb to connect to the database from python, but i get the error:

ORA-28759: failure to open file

My code is the standard connection code:

```
import oracledb
oracledb.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_18_5")

dbadw = """###fromtnsnames"""


connx = oracledb.connect(user='my_user', password ='my_password',dsn=dbadw , encoding="UTF-8")

c= connx.cursor()
```

without initializing oracle_client the error im getting is:

```
DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=r+tcRVTAlqmL/bxaTd38UA==).
DPY-6000: Listener refused connection. (Similar to ORA-12506)
```

The user im using to connect to the database is not administrator but i checked that i can open and write files and write files in the wallet directory

Im using jupyter notebook

I also tried with cx_Oracle, but pip install cx_Oracle throws error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools" which i cannot install since im not admin.
I checked many other posts on this same error but i didn´t get anywhere

Any other info i can give to solve this let me know
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error `ORA-28759: failure to open file` is generally due to the fact that your `sqlnet.ora` file doesn't have a valid value in its `WALLET_LOCATION` entry. This must be the directory in which the file `cwallet.sso` is found.

The error `DPY-6005` with the phrase `Similar to ORA-12506` raised in thin mode is telling you a similar thing. In thin mode you must specify the location of the wallet in the `wallet_location` parameter. You also (by default) need to specify the `wallet_password` parameter.

The [documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-databases) for connecting to Cloud databases should cover any remaining questions you might have!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this same problem in the future, i really struggled with this problem, but the answer from anthony helped me a lot.

What i did is i followed the steps followed this steps in the documentation

Basically, copy the tnsname.ora, sqlnet.ora and cwallet.sso to the instantclient/network/admin directory, or you could opt for any directory as long as you specify it in the sqlnet.ora file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One side note is that Instant Client 18.5 is really old.  Use the latest 19c release.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Oracle client 18 (I never heard about 18.5) is not the latest version, however I would not consider it as "really old". Here on SO you get questions where people still use version 11 or older.

Comment: @Wernfried, yes - there *is* client 18.5 (I use it). I also have 11g database. And some 10gs as well (in read-only mode, though, for *old* applications).

Comment: 18.5 is 4.5 years older than 19.20. Since 19c Client will connect to the same DBs that 18c will, I'd strongly encourage upgrading.  And 19c is the LTS release meaning even more release updates will be made in the future.  There have been some changes for Autonomous DB hostname matching that aren't in 18.5, see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html